# Using Javascript to update the href link text in a td cell in an onClick call

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table as follows:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Source</th>
            <th>Url</th>
            <th>Referenceid</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td title="12345">12345</td>
            <td title="https://example1.com"><a href="https://example1.com">https://example1.com</a></td>
            <td title="2">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td title="12345">12345</td>
            <td title="https://example2.com"><a href="https://example2.com">https://example2.com</a></td>
            <td title="1">1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to add an onClick handler so when the cell that is an Url gets clicked, it changes the text itself.  However I've tried getting the element and then setting it using `element.innerText=<a href="https://example1.com>newUrl</a>` as well as `element.textContent=...` and `element.innerHtml`, however none of them seems to update the url as I expect it (keeping it an `<a href>` clickable  with just updated text (sometimes it turns up as `[Object object]` and other times it turns up as escaped HTML.

How do I update the text for the `<a href>` properly in an onClick handler with basic javascript (no jQuery or anything)?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any `addEventListener("click", ...)` code in your post? As for how you update an href property of an anchor element: literally like that. You get a reference to the anchor element (e.g using `evt.target.querySelector("a")` in your click handler) and then setting `thatElement.href = "....."`, which is _not_ the same as updating the text users see, because that's `thatElement.textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a `forEach()` loop on the node list of your `<td>` elements and target the elements `firstChild`, use an `eventlistener` for click to and then change the `outerHTML`...

I added a class to the table data tags to target the elements. Run the value and index through the `forEach` loop function and use the index - `i` to get the event being clicked and the value - `v` to target the element...

```js
const td = document.querySelectorAll('.td');

td.forEach(function(v, i) {
  td[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    // `this` can also be used here in substitute with the value passed through the forEach loop
    // this.firstChild.outerHTML = "some new link";
    // The following will change the actual HTML of the TD elements firstChild so the <a> tag will be the 
    // string of HTML defined in the quotes below... 
    v.firstChild.outerHTML = "<a href='stackoverflow.com' target='_blank'>StakOverflow</a>";
  })
})
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>Url</th>
      <th>Referenceid</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td title="12345">12345</td>
      <td class="td" title="https://example1.com"><a href="#">https://example1.com</a></td>
      <td title="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td title="12345">12345</td>
      <td class="td" title="https://example2.com"><a href="#">https://example2.com</a></td>
      <td title="1">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***NOTE:*** If you ONLY want to change the text in between the `<a>` tag, then target the `textContent` like so...

```js
const td = document.querySelectorAll('.td');

td.forEach(function(v, i) {
  td[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.firstChild.textContent = "StakOverflow";
  })
})
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Source</th>
      <th>Url</th>
      <th>Referenceid</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td title="12345">12345</td>
      <td class="td" title="https://example1.com"><a href="#">https://example1.com</a></td>
      <td title="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td title="12345">12345</td>
      <td class="td" title="https://example2.com"><a href="#">https://example2.com</a></td>
      <td title="1">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function on your script.js

something like this

```
document.querySelector('#yourTd').addEventListener('click', function(){

   document.querySelector('#yourTd').innerHtml = "text you want to show"

}
```